# How to ignore parent container on UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've got a UserControl, let's call it "MyUserControl", reusable across the project, like this:

```
<WrapPanel> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Now I'm using a custom control called "TwoColumnGrid" found in codeproject.
Full [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238307/A-Two-Column-Grid-for-WPF).
Short version http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TwoColumnGrid/child-ordering.png
And I'm doing this:

```
<Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
<MyUserControl />
<TextBlock />
<TextBox />
</Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
```

As it is, the TwoColumnGrid doesn't work. I want to make it think MyUserControl is the two elements it contains. As such:

```
<Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
<TextBlock />
<TextBox />
</Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
```

I've tried toying with the visualtree, adding it programmatically and creating the object purely programmatically. 
Managed to make it work by removing and adding to the children but the binding wasn't working, which it was doing it by XAML.

Figured the good people of SO could help, any ideas?

EDIT:
I use MyUserControl more than once on TwoColumnGrid. Like so:

```
<Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
    <MyUserControl />
    <TextBlock />
    <TextBox />
    <MyUserControl />
 </Custom:TwoColumnGrid>
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with WPF, but I would assume that you *can't* make it think it's two elements, because it's *not*.  And assuming that it is could break your code later if you add a third element to the user control (perhaps a hidden field?).

Comment: Not sure about that, by creating them on code behind it worked but the bindings never stuck even though on XAML they worked. The hidden field wouldn't work the usercontrol would still be counted as one element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create 2 small controls (one for the TextBlock, the other for the Combobox) and use both to create MyUserControl. That means you can use MyUserControl as the big peace and you can use the 2 smaller pieces in your TwoColumnGrid without duplicating code/XAML.

Comment: Then you may lose any special logic that ties them together, though.

Comment: Yes, Bobson is right, I should have said but I'm calling the usercontrol more than once and it's coupled with bindings. In a way possible but not pratical.